# JS: Why would click event not be bubbling?

Tags: javascript

I have a click event on a child nested within a parent element.  I am logging the target of the event but the click event is only happening when clicking on the `#item` element, not the parent container.

```js
let item = document.getElementById('item');
item.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.target)
})
```

```css
.container {
  background: pink;
}

#item {
  width: 90px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="item">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What were you expecting instead? The listener is attached to the child, not to the parent, so why would a click outside the child result in the listener firing?

Comment: if I had set that eventListener to `capture` rather than bubble, shouldn't that trigger the child listeners?

Comment: The DOM3 description of  [Event dispatch and DOM event flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) can help make things less mysterious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way events (which propagate) work is:

- Some element on the page dispatches the event. For example, let's say that an element is clicked.
- The **capturing** phase of the event starts. Starting from the root element (`window`), any *capturing* event listeners for that event fire. For example, listeners on `window` will fire before listeners on `document`, and listeners on `document` will fire before listeners on inner elements. The only elements which will have listeners fire are those that are ancestors of the element that **dispatched** the element.
- At the end of the capturing phase, listeners on the element that dispatched the event will fire.
- The bubbling phase starts. Listeners for the event will fire in the following order:

  - The parent element of the element that dispatched the event
  - The parent element of *that* parent

    ...
  - The window

As you can see, if an event is dispatched to an element, the only elements that will have listeners triggered are the element's parents, grandparents, etc. Listeners on child elements will not fire. This is why, if there's a click on your `#container`, *outside* the `.item`, the listener on the `.item` will not fire.